# How to mock ODataQueryOptions [Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData, Version=7.3.0.0]?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, odata, moq

I am writing unit test for a controller with ODataQueryOptions and unable to mock it.

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<WeatherForecast> Get(ODataQueryOptions<WeatherForecast> options)
{
    logger.LogInformation($"Call to end point [{options.Request.Method}]: Host :'{options.Request.Host}' Endpoint : '{options.Request.Path}'");
    logger.LogInformation($"Query string: '{options.Request.QueryString}'");

    return weatherForecastService.Get().Entity;
}
```

Trying something like

```
public class WeatherServiceTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IWeatherService> weatherServiceMock;
    private readonly Mock<ILogger<WeatherController>> loggerMock;
    private readonly Mock<ODataQueryOptions<Weather>> optionsMock;
    private readonly WeatherController weatherController;

    public WeatherServiceTests()
    {
        weatherServiceMock = new Mock<IWeatherService>();
        loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<WeatherController>>();
        optionsMock = new Mock<ODataQueryOptions<Weather>>();
        weatherController = new WeatherController(loggerMock.Object, weatherServiceMock.Object);
    }

    private ApiResponse<IQueryable<Weather>> GetWeatherMockup()
    {
        var weather = new List<Weather>
        {
            new Weather {Content = "Content", Header = "Header", Source = "Source"}
        }.AsQueryable();
        return new ApiResponse<IQueryable<Weather>>(weather);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void WeatherData_Get()
    {
        weatherServiceMock.Setup(x => x.Get()).Returns(GetWeatherMockup());
        var response = weatherController.Get(optionsMock.Object).ToList();

        Assert.NotNull(response);
        Assert.True(response.Count == 1);
    }
}
```

How can I mock ODataQueryOptions? I have referred to few answered question regarding the same but they are or little use.

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Are you getting an error? What is the problem?

Comment: I am unable to find a solution to mock ODataQueryOptions<IInterface> options.